# Visual Studio: CTRL+M CTRL+V (.Net MVC)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've seen this combination (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) used to create Views for ASP .Net MVC with Visual Studio, but it doesn't work on my computer. So I was wondering where does it come from and how to make it work?

**Solution:** Apparently MVC was not registered within Visual Studio, so I had to reinstall it. The shortcut is added by MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be inside of a controller action method (as in - cursor has to be placed in a method) for the shortcut to work.

Comment: VS 2008 SP1. Is there an extension for MVC? I don't think I have it installed.

Comment: I'm assuming you have MVC framework installed (RC2 being the latest I think - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3b537c55-0948-4e6a-bf8c-aa1a78878da0&displaylang=en#filelist) - if so that's all you need to install - there are no special extensions beyond that that I'm aware of.

Comment: I've just reinstalled MVC 1 and there is not even an MVC project type in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> did not work for me as well on a new computer, the problem was Bing bar which was automatically installed. The only solution is to uninstall the bar! Disabling the bar has no effect.

Also look here: [Ctrl+M stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872144/vs2010-ctrlm-keyboard-shortcut-has-stopped-working)