# VS2010 CTRL+M keyboard shortcut has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a strange problem which seems to have recently appeared. I used to be able to press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to 'collapse to definitions' in VS2010 when editing code, but it seems suddenly the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> key seems to have stopped working. When I now press the key combination I get the Open File dialogue.

I have tried the obvious things like resetting the keyboard scheme in *Tools > Options* but this has had no effect, I did also check that the default mapping for the keys were present and no other settings were overriding it in VS2010.

I have tried searching for an answer on the internet but can't find any other solutions. Has anyone heard of this happening before and do you know of a way to resolve this problem.

In addition, I very recently installed the new *Windows Live Essentials 2011* suite, I am starting to wonder if this has any relation to this, although I'm not sure why it would! I have not had any of the apps running whilst VS2010 has been open. This could be of course  a red herring!

Comment: When you press Ctrl-M do you see the following text in the status bar: "(Ctrl-M) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord..."? As Ctrl-M, Ctrl-O is doing the same as Ctrl-O it seems that Visual Studio never receives Ctrl-M. A broken keyboard perhaps?

Comment: No I don't get anything in the statusbar at all, I do if I use the CTRL+K as you would expect. Hmmmm... Don't think it's a broken keyboard, just seems to be a broken CTRL+M

Comment: Further to above, I have also tried using the 'Press shortcut keys' option under VS2010 Tools > Options just to see if the key combination works at all and I can get every combination of the keyboard+M to appear but CTRL+M is the only combination to not appear! Very weird.

Comment: And more... I now think it is Windows 7, as I've just tried mapping that particular shortcut in another program (Notepad++) and that too fails to detect that particular keyboard combination. How do I find out what keys are mapped to what in Windows, any idea's?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Start killing processes with Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.  You'll eventually find the one that's sucking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> with a windows hook.

---

Just to confirm, from more than one question and comment about this, it is the Microsoft Bing toolbar that causes the problem.  Uninstalling it is the only known workaround right now.

Comment: That was actually a good idea and I managed to narrow it down to the Bing bar, which I had disabled in IE but it still had a process running. It was installed with the new Windows Live Essentials 2011, killing that process brought back my CTRL+M key combo. Thanks very much!

Comment: Just to finally add, I had to uninstall Bing bar from Add/Remove programs as the process kept on appearing again after a few seconds.

Comment: wow. just wow. and i was figuring for hours what the heck is wrong with my computers. thanks.

Comment: Camtasia Recorder also uses the Ctrl+M combination for the Marker hotkey. You can reassign it in the tools/options/hotkeys.

Comment: Removing the Bing Bar worked for me as well. Thanks a bunch. :)

Comment: thanks, thought I was going nuts. this wouldve taken me forever to figure out !

Comment: @s.r.: Sorry. I accidentally turned your answer into a comment.

Answer (score 17):

Skype was the culprit for me. Turns out I enabled keyboard shortcuts for it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> was "Mute Microphone". Hope this helps others.

Comment: Skype was the culprit for me as well. Normally I don't run Skype and Visual Studio at the same time so I didn't encounter this until two months after installing Skype...

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh! Thank you. That was driving me insane.

Comment: Skype also has the problem of being difficult to close ("closing" it actually puts it invisibly in the bg most of the times). In my case, there was no indication of it being open other than in the task manager.

Comment: this is so true happened on me while i call to my colleague will typing code in VSCode

Answer (score 3):

I have Skype installed.
It had CTRL + M enabled for muting microphone.

Check all open programs and check their settings/options/preferences to see if they are using system wide shortcut keys and disable/modify accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running VS2010 inside VMWare Fusion on a Mac.

For me, it stopped working after updating VMWare Fusion to version 4.1.2

I fixed it by unticking "Minimize Window (⌘ - M)" in Preferences > Keyboard & Mouse > Fusion Shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Bing Bar was installed but disabled in both FF and IE (FF had disabled it itself on security grounds, in IE I disabled it).  I couldn't find any process specifically for the Bing Bar, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> stopped working if IE was running.  Unistalled the Bing Bar and the problem went away.  Thanks:)

Also, just to confirm it's not a Visual Studio issue - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> stopped working in other programs too (at least SQL Navigator, which is quite an old program that I doubt is aware of and trying to use the Bing Bar - my guess is that it takes over <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> from everything).

Answer (score 0):

Reboot worked for me.

I experienced this same issue out of nowhere (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> stopped responding).

I read the suggestions here but I could not find what process was causing it. I rebooted my laptop & the problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

The culprit for me was an AutoHotKey script that had Ctrl+M bound but not doing anything. The solution was to remove the un-used binding from the script and re-load the script. After that, everything is working.