# Collapse/Expand code definitions not working - VS2K5, 2K8

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, keyboard-shortcuts

I can no longer collapse or expand code definitions in Visual Studio 2005 or 2008.  Don't remember exactly when it started, so I'm stumped relating it to a plug-in or other software install.  I checked Edit - Outlining - and Auto Outlining is enabled.  Keyboard is OK.  It will work if I navigate to the menu and toggle with the mouse.  Its just the keyboard shortcuts that no longer work.

Please help, I'm lost without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools + Customize, Keyboard button.  [Rebind the keys](http://www.mobydisk.com/softdev/techinfo/dotnetkeyboard.html).  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> is `Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions`.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that is the correct answer, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.  Turns out my PC won't except a key combo of Ctrl+M.  Tried multiple keyboards and checked device driver - nothing.  I rebinded (using the method you described above) but substituted "N" for "M".  I'll just have to deal until I can get a new PC.

Comment: Do you have Bing bar installed?  It eats Ctrl+M keystrokes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872144/vs2010-ctrlm-keyboard-shortcut-has-stopped-working/3873059#3873059

Comment: Why yes I do, and killing it restored my ctrl+M.  I gotta get my daily rewards (to convert to MS points, so I'll just need to kill it while I develop). Thanks for your help!  I'm off to sharpen my Stack Overflow searching skills.