# VS2010 CTRL+L keyboard shortcut has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I use CTRL + L all the time to delete rows in visual studio, but the shortcut stopped working recently. My symptoms are similar to the ones described here: [VS2010 CTRL+M keyboard shortcut has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3872144/138938) after the Bing Toolbar was installed.

CTRL+M works for me, and I don't have Bing installed. I *have* installed a few apps recently, including Paint.NET, Gimp, and Directory Opus, all three of which have have CTRL+L keyboard shortcuts that are working as expected.

Has anybody run into this issue and know how I can resolve it?

Comment: Have you checked the Keyboard tab in Options?

Comment: That was it. My keyboard settings had "Visual Basic 6" selected in the "Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme" drop-down. I changed it to "(Default)" and now the shortcut works as expected. @SLaks, if you change your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Keyboard tab in Options.