# Collapse to Definitions doesn't work in VS2013 and ReSharper 8.2

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, code-folding, outlining

I'm running VS2013 Pro Update 2, and R# 8.2, and I'm unable to collapse my code to definitions. This is true on my work machine and home workstation. When I click Collapse to Definitions, the `using` statements collapse, but that's all. It doesn't matter where my cursor is in the code. At work, my OS is Windows 7; at home it's Windows 8.1.

I had no problems with VS 2012 Pro and R# 8. This is exclusive to VS2013.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and solved it? Google isn't showing anything promising...

Comment: Just to be sure, could you please post a piece of code that you are trying to collapse and for which it doesnt work? Possibly have a look at this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3872144/3242721), even though your collapse seems to be partially working (usings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr- Update VS2013 to Update 3, and then disable and re-enable R#.**

--

At home I was running VS2013**u3**, the latest. Disabling and then re-enabling R# via Tools > Options fixed the collapsing issue.

At work, I was running VS2013**u2**. I tried the same process as above (disabling and then re-enabling) R#, which did NOT work, so I checked VS version numbers to make sure my work setup was the same as my home setup. It was then that I discovered that I was a rev behind. After installing Update 3, collapsing to definitions now works as it should, and there was no need to do the disable/enable dance.

Answer (score 2):

I also found out that if you have C# outline 2013 installed and enabled, It does not work.

I disabled this extension and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have VS2013u4 and have been having this problem for awhile now. I learned there is an 'Automatic Outlining' option that is overriding the Ctrl+M, O shortcut. To fix right-click in the text editor > Outlining > Stop Outlining. The shortcut should work after that.