# Visual Studio 2012 Ctrl + Alt + Arrow keys not working for shortcut assignments?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just started using Resharper and am liking it so far, except it changed the way Alt-Up and Down moved lines of code around in the text editor, Resharper wants that to mean Goto Next / Previous method. I wanted to keep it as the original, and assign the Gotos as Ctrl + Alt Up / Down or Alt Gr + Up / Down.

It seems that assigning commands to Ctrl + Alt + Up / Down arrows keyboard shortcut is not possible in Visual Studio, can anybody confirm this? Why is this I wonder.

This is not specific to Resharper I don't think, can anybody that's not using Resharper try to assign some command to Alt Gr + Up / Down arrows and see if it works?

Warning: If you have Intel Graphics running, the Ctrl + Alt + Up / Down arrows are set to flip the screen around 180° - which I never use. You can disable this by right clicking on the desktop, selecting Graphic Options, Hot Keys and Disable. I have disabled these but I wonder if they are interfering still?

Comment: Sure, [here is a good example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873059/17034).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found it! I had this issue with CTRL+ALT+LEFT OR RIGHT ARROWS and I killed the igfxHK Module process and it worked! Even though I'd already disabled Hot Keys that didn't do it, the module was still holding on to the key combination for some reason.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I went to intel graphics command center and changed the already disabled shortcut to `ctrl + shift + arrow` and it worked (this is in 2020)

Comment: @ado387 oh man thanks that was also intel graphics also stealing the shortcuts even though as you said the shortcuts were disabled, I just changed them and re-disabled them and that worked... what a bummer seriously, thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio Code. Killing the igfxHK module fixed it.