# Visual Studio: CTRL-TAB doesn't always work

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tabs, shortcut

This post originally related to "Visual Studio", but affects other similar applications.
There are a number of posts dealing with a problem where the tab navigation panel appears but requires a click etc to dismiss. These seem to be solved by fiddling with the magnifyer, narrator etc. None of these solutions apply to my problem - which is that, in VS2012, ctrl-tab brings up the two-column navigation panel, repeated presses of tab moves through the lists as normal, but, on release of both keys, the focussed tab is NOT changed. With the nav panel displayed, you can click on it with the mouse and the focussed tab is changed as expected.

The issue seems to have arisen after installing VS2012. VS2010 is also installed and oddly now also exhibits the same problem, even though I have never had the problem until now. When you re-start VS, all works fine, but after a time ctrl-tab stops working normally. It has been seen to stop working without doing anything other than pressing ctrl-tab a few times i.e. not going to any other VS panel or doing a build etc.

This is a major problem with productivity as I use this constantly to switch between tabs. I know that I can change the shortcut to switch between documents without showing the navigation panel, but I prefer to see this panel, rather than switching 'blind'.

Does anyone know why this might be happening or how to fix it? I have done a full Windows update (Svr 2008 R2).

NOTE1 - I now see the same problem with a new installation of VS2013 and also in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 - on ctrl-tab you see the two-col panel but whatever you select doesn't change the pane in view (unless you click the panel with the mouse).
When ctrl-tab is not working in the VS-based apps, it DOES continue working in, say, Notepad++, which suggests an MS-VS problem.

NOTE2 - The problem does not exist when you use the on-screen keyboard! It seems that using the OSK causes ctr-tab to work again with the real keyboard, but it breaks quickly when you start almost any other application, but it always works with the OSK. The problem is unrelated to the physical keyboard as I have tried other keyboards.

Thanks

Comment: I can confirm that this problem exists in VS2013 Pro. I'm using Win7 (64-bit) if that has something to do. On my machine, pressing Ctrl + Tab shows a glimpse of the document-switch window, for maybe a millisecond or so, and then that window disappears, with no switching having taken place. Anyone from MS reading this?

Comment: Same kind of problem as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873059/17034).  Ctrl+Tab is popular, add the language bar and VS add-ins to that list.