# Start Without Debugging shortcut does not work in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, shortcut, visual-studio-express

Start Without Debugging shortcut does not work in Visual Studio. What can I do about it?

I set the shortcut for this to be `Ctrl+R`.
[image]
[image]

When I click the option to start without debugging in the task bar the program runs successfully as expected. But when I try to run the program using `Ctrl+R` nothing happens.

What am I missing here?

I am using **Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873059/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `ctrl+r` is the first part of a chord. You could set the shortcut as `ctrl+r, ctrl+r`. See arrow in the picture.

[image: waiting for keystroke]